# Update Contents of JQueryUI Tooltip in Realtime on Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a follow/unfollow button and am using jQuery UI tooltips to display the button's title. When the button is clicked, I change the button's title + update the tooltip immediately (without the user having to move their mouse away and re-hover over the button) like so:

```
el.title = 'Follow';
$('#follow').tooltip("option", "content", "Follow");
$(this).mouseover();
```

Is there a way to replicate this behaviour on mobile devices? And if not, is there a better way to immediately update the tooltip content that will work for both desktop and mobile?

Comment: have you tested it in mobile device.. it will also work in mobile as well

Comment: @RahulMishra it works inconsistently on mobile - the first time the button is clicked the tooltip does not update, once the tooltip is closed and the button is clicked a few more times, yes, it works, but most users will not be rapidly toggling back and forth so I'm not comfortable saying it "works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the way I altered the tooltip's text to

```
$('#follow').tooltip("option", "content", "Follow");
$("#follow").data("ui-tooltip-title", "Follow");
$(".ui-tooltip-content").html($("#follow").data("ui-tooltip-title"));
```

which removes the need to trigger a mouseover event and so works the first time on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

On mobile you may need to resort to touch events for full consistency. A "click" on mobile is actually emulated; it is synthesized from a touchstart followed by a touchend on the same element. The mouseover/in and mouseexit/leave/out events are non-starters in touch devices.

I would try attaching the code sequence you've included above not only to a click event, but also to a touchend event.

For additional details on the touch event API, you can refer to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events); Apple has perhaps the longest-standing such document (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html). The latter page also has information on how some traditional mouse events are "inferred" by the touch device.